# Partial string matching in LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Consider following SQL statement -

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE FirstName LIKE '%IS%'
```

This is will search for customers having 'IS' as part of first name, right?

I like the same statement to be in LINQ -

```
var names = from cust in customers where cust.FirstName ......
```

I am unable to specify that condition. 
Can anybody help me out solve this.

Thanks for sharing your time and wisdom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most LINQ -> SQL translators will take a few regular methods from c# and translate them into SQL. Contains is a very common method to translate and works with linq2sql and EF

```
var names = from cust in customers 
            where cust.FirstName.Contains("IS")
            select cust;
```

**EDIT: (case insensitive)**

```
var names = from cust in customers 
            where cust.FirstName.ToLower().Contains("is")
            select cust;
```

Comment: @IrfanRaza what ORM are you using?

Comment: Luke its working, i found search is case sensitive. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @IrfanRaza yeah this will do an exact character match, you can do this case insensitive with something like the following (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

For Case insenstive `contains`, you can either convert the string to same case (lower or upper) or **its better** if you can use [String.IndexOf Method (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx)

```
var names = from cust in customers 
            where cust.FirstName.IndexOf("IS",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
            select cust;
```

Although the performance gain may be negligible from this method, but it will ensure a proper case insensitive comparison. Its always a good practice to use `StringComparison` enum for case insensitive string comparison. You may see: [The Turkish İ Problem and Why You Should Care](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var names = from cust in customers where cust.FirstName.Contains("IS")
```

Comment: Thanks Jen, you have the same answer as of Luke.

Comment: no problem :) Lukes anwser is more accurate, so you should mark that as the right anwser.